# Help with Error: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation

Tags: functions, evaluation, recursion, variable

I am quite new to Mathematica. Please excuse my mistakes. I would appreciate if you could help me with the following set of commands.

```
kw = 50
kc = 5
0 <= n <= 100
m=50
dnc = 2 nc
n1 := (kw - kc) /dnc
n2 := ( m kw - dnc )/(kw + kc)
n3 := ( m kw + dnc )/(kw - kc)
nc = n2 - n1 + 100 - n3

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of kw-kc.
```

As you might guess, the variables n1, n2, n3 and nc are simultaneously determined. I am able to solve this problem by hand of course. However, I will further need to plot some graphs and I need to be able to solve these values on Mathematica. I know that this is not a complicated problem. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `nc` is defined in terms of `n2`, which is defined in terms of `dnc`, which is defined in terms of `nc`, making an infinite loop.  Cant you explain exactly what you are trying to do?  Like, *what* are you trying to plot as a function of *what*?  why do you have `0<=n<=100`, when n doesn't appear anywhere else in your expression?  More explanation of what you are actually trying to do here will be necessary.

Comment: n indicates the location of any individual which can take a value in between 0 and 100, will be necessary later. n1, n2, and n3 denote the cutoffs at the equilibrium. nc denotes a particular mass of individuals, which has the form in the above formula. Overall, I am trying to solve for the equilibrium values.

I will plot the cost functions defined in terms of integrations, depending on the location of individuals, n.

Comment: So, you are actually trying to *solve* the equations for `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, and `nc`?  Then do `Solve[{dnc == 2 nc, n1 == (kw - kc)/dnc, n2 == (m kw - dnc)/(kw + kc),
   n3 == (m kw + dnc)/(kw - kc), nc == n2 - n1 + 100 - n3}, {n1, n2, 
  n3, dnc, nc}]`. You will need to clear your variables first.  You do *not* want them set to values: so do `Clear[n1, n2, d3, nc, dnc]` first.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.